# Using stored procedure parameters to return columns

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to write a stored procedure that will return a specific value base on two input parameters. The issue is trying to make one of the parameters refer to a column.

Here's my table:

```
CityID      CityName             London                               Paris                                   
----------- -------------------- --------------------------------------- --
1           London               0                                       60                                      
2           Paris                50                                      0                                       
3           Berlin               90                                      60                                      
4           Madrid               150                                     90                                      
5           Dublin               30                                      80                                      
6           Rome                 75                                      88
```

Is it possible to write a stored procedure along the lines of:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Price (@city1, @city2)
AS
    SELECT @city2 
    FROM dbo.MyTable
    WHERE CityName = @city1
```

Comment: What you're describing is dynamic SQL.  You want to pass in the name of a column and then return the value of that column for the matching city.  Right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'm not familiar with Dynamic Sql I'm afraid.

Comment: This question can't accurately be answered without knowing the RDBMS you're using.  Seems like MS SQL but please confirm along with the version.

Comment: Yes, its MS SQL. Im using SQL server 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something this like which verifies the existence of the column name before trying to run the dynamic SQL statement:

```
create procedure dbo.GetPrice(@city nvarchar(50), @column nvarchar(200)) as
begin

if (not exists (select *
                from sys.columns
                where object_id = object_id('dbo.MyTable') and name = @column))
    return;
else begin
    declare @sql nvarchar(max) =
        'SELECT [' + @column + '] FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE CityName = ''' + @city + '''';

    execute sp_ExecuteSQL @sql;
end;

end;
```

Comment: I'm getting ''Error converting data type varchar to numeric.'' Checking the existence of the column isn't necessary for me at the moment.

Comment: I just tested this locally and it's working fine when I run `execute dbo.GetPrice 'test', 'London';`

Comment: _Checking the existence of the column isn't necessary for me at the moment._  It is necessary if you want to avoid people running arbitrary SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make use of dynamic sql.

```
CREATE PROC Price (@City1, @City2)
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Sql = 'SELECT ' + @City2 + ' FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE CityName = ''' + 
@City1 +  ''''

EXEC sp_execute @Sql
END
```

Comment: This doesn't parse.  Not only that, but what do you plan to do if someone passes `@City2 = '0; drop table users; select null'`

Answer (score 0):

Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_Price]
    @city1      Varchar,
    ------------------------------------------------
    @City2      VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL OUT

AS
BEGIN

```
 SELECT @city2 
FROM dbo.MyTable
WHERE CityName = @city1
```

END

--- Create the stored procedure, and if you are using the sql server, 
right click on the stored procedure and click execute stored procedure
enter the city1 value, while select null for the city 2 
and execute

Comment: Try to use the  above query to create a stored procedure